# laying online stream in HTML webpage

Tags: html, m3u

I  want to play this audio live stream in html browser
http://uk3.internet-radio.com:8405/live

I tried several players with no hope
any player than can do that? or plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    </head>
    <body>
      <video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">
         <source src="http://uk3.internet-radio.com:8405/live" type="audio/aac">
      </video>
    </body>
</html>
```

To try, save it as .html file and run.